# Page break options in a TextField

Tags: pdf, page-breaking, page, textfield

Yesterday I helped a friend who was working on a template of a school certificate. Basically he has written it with OpenOffice. Now he wanted to see how it looks in MS Office. There are different formular fields to fill, from name over grades to remarks.

I started working on a PDF formular template with LaTeX and figured out that we get a problem where we already had another when opening the OO-Document in MS Office. It's about the textfield for remarks. For that it is possible in both Office to define in the paragraphs register of the settings for page break.

One point it was that MS Office doesn't figure out the settings done with OOffice so they got to be made again with MS Office and simply saved. If the setting I can't remember is not set the textfield will be shown on the next page if it grows with the input. If it is done the textfield get split if the page size is reached and the rest the user enters is shown on the next page.

To be clear: I want to achieve a formular textfield in LaTeX like this, that grows with the input of the user, also over more pages if the user of the PDF formular has more to say. Is that possible or does it just work with other ways of making document templates?
I didn't test if it is possible with Acrobat to convert the Office document to a PDF file with the same functionality.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I must admit that I do not really understand your question, but for instance `mdframed` has boxes that can go over several pages.

Comment: Let's say I make a PDF form with input fields. One field might be a comment, normally a multiline textfield that should now get a dynamic height instead of a fixed. And then it gets bigger, up to the end of the page, it should automatically do a page break and this textfield continues on the next page while someone inputs his comment to the multiline textfield.

Comment: I'm not sure that PDF can do this.